# overflow: auto; is it supported for <td> of a html table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

There are long texts or string for html table `<td>`.

Now I want to break the line/texts/string.

overflow: auto; is it supported for `<td>` of a html table? I tried it it doesn't work.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a CSS attribute white-space

```
white-space:normal;
```

Comment: white-space: normal; OR white-space: wrap; ?

Answer (score 0):

if your server side language is PHP you can word-wrap your data came from PHP using this function
[php wordwrap function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)